# Degrouping from one row per group to one row per subject

Tags: r, reshape

I have data where each row represents a household, and I would like to have one row per individual in the different households.

The data looks similar to this:

```
df <- data.frame(village = rep("aaa",5),household_ID = c(1,2,3,4,5),name_1 = c("Aldo","Giovanni","Giacomo","Pippo","Pippa"),outcome_1 = c("yes","no","yes","no","no"),name_2 = c("John","Mary","Cindy","Eva","Doron"),outcome_2 = c("yes","no","no","no","no"))
```

I would still like to keep the wide format of the data, just with one individual (and related outcome variables) per row. I could find examples that tell how to do the opposite, going from individual to grouped data using `dcast`, but I could not find examples of this problem I am facing now.

I have tried with melt

```
reshape2::melt(df, id.vars = "household_ID")
```

but I get a long format data.

Any suggestions welcome...

Thank you

Comment: How do you define an individual? with only `name_1` or `name_1` and name_2` or something else? Most importantly, how do you want to select 1 row for each individual? Based on what values? It would be helpful if you could also share your expected output.

Comment: Does my answer work for you? Hope that I don't misunderstand what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Use `pivot_longer()` in `tidyr`, and set `".value"` in `names_to` to indicate new column names from the pattern of the original column names.

```
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(village, household_ID),
               names_to = c(".value", "n"),
               names_sep = "_")

# # A tibble: 10 x 5
#    village household_ID n     name     outcome
#    <fct>          <dbl> <chr> <fct>    <fct>  
#  1 aaa                1 1     Aldo     yes    
#  2 aaa                1 2     John     yes    
#  3 aaa                2 1     Giovanni no     
#  4 aaa                2 2     Mary     no     
#  5 aaa                3 1     Giacomo  yes    
#  6 aaa                3 2     Cindy    no     
#  7 aaa                4 1     Pippo    no     
#  8 aaa                4 2     Eva      no     
#  9 aaa                5 1     Pippa    no     
# 10 aaa                5 2     Doron    no
```

---

***Data***

```
df <- structure(list(village = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "aaa", class = "factor"), 
    household_ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), name_1 = structure(c(1L, 
    3L, 2L, 5L, 4L), .Label = c("Aldo", "Giacomo", "Giovanni", 
    "Pippa", "Pippo"), class = "factor"), outcome_1 = structure(c(2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("no", "yes"), class = "factor"), 
    name_2 = structure(c(4L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("Cindy", 
    "Doron", "Eva", "John", "Mary"), class = "factor"), outcome_2 = structure(c(2L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("no", "yes"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```